# backfill pandas dataframe column using a condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a pandas dataframe with 50 million records and what I am trying to do is backfill based on a condition. As we can see that the timestamps for name 800A and Barber align so I assume that the data belongs to same name and it is just an error while recording the data. The same goes with name Mia.

This is just the sample data.

my dataframe looks like this.

`datetime       name     dischargeDate       HR Sp  x_inc   vs_inc  rec_num
01-05 18:04:50  Zawisza  14-01-05 18:05:00  119 98  FALSE   TRUE    6458445
01-05 18:04:55  Zawisza  14-01-05 18:05:00  120 97  FALSE   TRUE    6458445
01-05 18:05:00  Zawisza  14-01-05 18:05:00          FALSE   FALSE

01-29 17:58:45  800A     14-01-29 17:59:10          FALSE   FALSE

01-29 17:58:50  800A     14-01-29 17:59:10  139     FALSE   TRUE

01-29 17:58:55  800A     14-01-29 17:59:10  138     FALSE   TRUE

01-29 17:59:00  800A     14-01-29 17:59:10  138 96  FALSE   TRUE

01-29 17:59:15  Barber   14-01-29 18:17:15  138 96  FALSE   TRUE    7192783
01-29 17:59:20  Barber   14-01-29 18:17:15  138 96  FALSE   TRUE    7192783
01-29 17:59:25  Barber   14-01-29 18:17:15  138 95  FALSE   TRUE    7192783
03-04 21:19:45  800A     15-03-05 01:00:15          FALSE   FALSE

03-05 00:53:10  800A     15-03-05 01:00:15          FALSE   FALSE

03-05 00:55:50  800A     15-03-05 01:00:15      94  FALSE   TRUE

03-05 00:55:55  800A     15-03-05 01:00:15  81  93  FALSE   TRUE

03-05 00:56:00  800A     15-03-05 01:00:15  89  93  FALSE   TRUE

03-05 01:00:20  Mia      15-03-05 04:13:15  70  93  FALSE   TRUE    6728923
03-05 01:00:25  Mia      15-03-05 04:13:15  70  93  FALSE   TRUE    6728923
03-05 01:00:30  Mia      15-03-05 04:13:15  70  94  FALSE   TRUE    6728923`

Now I am trying to backfill the record numbers(rec_num) column until it maps the bool condition False False in both the x_inc and vs_inc columns.

Actual output:

`datetime       name     dischargeDate       HR Sp  x_inc   vs_inc  rec_num
01-05 18:04:50  Zawisza  14-01-05 18:05:00  119 98  FALSE   TRUE    6458445
01-05 18:04:55  Zawisza  14-01-05 18:05:00  120 97  FALSE   TRUE    6458445
01-05 18:05:00  Zawisza  14-01-05 18:05:00          FALSE   FALSE   7192783
01-29 17:58:45  800A     14-01-29 17:59:10          FALSE   FALSE   7192783 
01-29 17:58:50  800A     14-01-29 17:59:10  139     FALSE   TRUE    7192783 
01-29 17:58:55  800A     14-01-29 17:59:10  138     FALSE   TRUE    7192783 
01-29 17:59:00  800A     14-01-29 17:59:10  138 96  FALSE   TRUE    7192783 
01-29 17:59:15  Barber   14-01-29 18:17:15  138 96  FALSE   TRUE    7192783
01-29 17:59:20  Barber   14-01-29 18:17:15  138 96  FALSE   TRUE    7192783
01-29 17:59:25  Barber   14-01-29 18:17:15  138 95  FALSE   TRUE    7192783
03-04 21:19:45  800A     15-03-05 01:00:15          FALSE   FALSE   6728923
03-05 00:53:10  800A     15-03-05 01:00:15          FALSE   FALSE   6728923
03-05 00:55:50  800A     15-03-05 01:00:15      94  FALSE   TRUE    6728923
03-05 00:55:55  800A     15-03-05 01:00:15  81  93  FALSE   TRUE    6728923
03-05 00:56:00  800A     15-03-05 01:00:15  89  93  FALSE   TRUE    6728923
03-05 01:00:20  Mia      15-03-05 04:13:15  70  93  FALSE   TRUE    6728923
03-05 01:00:25  Mia      15-03-05 04:13:15  70  93  FALSE   TRUE    6728923
03-05 01:00:30  Mia      15-03-05 04:13:15  70  94  FALSE   TRUE    6728923`

Expected output:

`datetime       name     dischargeDate       HR Sp  x_inc   vs_inc  rec_num
01-05 18:04:50  Zawisza  14-01-05 18:05:00  119 98  FALSE   TRUE    6458445
01-05 18:04:55  Zawisza  14-01-05 18:05:00  120 97  FALSE   TRUE    6458445
01-05 18:05:00  Zawisza  14-01-05 18:05:00          FALSE   FALSE

01-29 17:58:45  800A     14-01-29 17:59:10          FALSE   FALSE

01-29 17:58:50  800A     14-01-29 17:59:10  139     FALSE   TRUE    7192783 
01-29 17:58:55  800A     14-01-29 17:59:10  138     FALSE   TRUE    7192783 
01-29 17:59:00  800A     14-01-29 17:59:10  138 96  FALSE   TRUE    7192783 
01-29 17:59:15  Barber   14-01-29 18:17:15  138 96  FALSE   TRUE    7192783
01-29 17:59:20  Barber   14-01-29 18:17:15  138 96  FALSE   TRUE    7192783
01-29 17:59:25  Barber   14-01-29 18:17:15  138 95  FALSE   TRUE    7192783
03-04 21:19:45  800A     15-03-05 01:00:15          FALSE   FALSE

03-05 00:53:10  800A     15-03-05 01:00:15          FALSE   FALSE

03-05 00:55:50  800A     15-03-05 01:00:15      94  FALSE   TRUE    6728923
03-05 00:55:55  800A     15-03-05 01:00:15  81  93  FALSE   TRUE    6728923
03-05 00:56:00  800A     15-03-05 01:00:15  89  93  FALSE   TRUE    6728923
03-05 01:00:20  Mia      15-03-05 04:13:15  70  93  FALSE   TRUE    6728923
03-05 01:00:25  Mia      15-03-05 04:13:15  70  93  FALSE   TRUE    6728923
03-05 01:00:30  Mia      15-03-05 04:13:15  70  94  FALSE   TRUE    6728923`

I am using `df['rec_num'].fillna(method='bfill')` but it fills completely which is not my ideal solution. I would appreciate if I can get any suggestions to this problem(or if there is any better approach). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you upload a csv (dataset) to reproduce? You can add a link (Gdrive shared) in you question...

Comment: Andre Araujo. here is the link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gBbaQozykOemncWcwqs7jW6vjDPbe6ke/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you be more clear about what do you expect? Eg: Fill the rec_num(column) with just when the x_inc  and  vs_inc fields is not  FALSE?

Comment: Hi Andre. So basically I want to back fill the record numbers if HR = True and SP = True or HR=False and SP = True or HR = True and SP = False but not HR = False and SP = False. Let me know if it answered your question.

Comment: Perfect. I understand! Just the last doubt. The field rec_num is a timestamp of datetime column?

Comment: No, its the record number for that particular name.

Comment: OK. So, in order to get the id (to fill) from a name I have to compare previous records check the name vs rec_num?

Comment: In order to backfill the record number. Yes

Comment: @AbalanMusk : Check below added answer, I think you need the same. :) let me know if you  need anything else.

Answer (score 4):

**Using a boolean mask and [`np.where()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) you can use this:**

```
cond=(df.x_inc == False) & (df.vs_inc == False) #creates a boolean mask where both columns are false
df['new_rec']=np.where(~cond,df.rec_num.bfill(),df.rec_num) #does a backfill on where condition is not met
print(df)
```

**Note :** *you can reassign  the values to the old column named `rec_num` instead of creating a new column. I added that so you could compare. Also this should be the fastest method since vectorized*

```
    datetime            name    dischargeDate       HR      Sp      x_inc   vs_inc  rec_num     new_rec
0   2019-05-01 18:04:50 Zawisza 2005-01-14 18:05:00 119.0   98.0    False   True    6458445.0   6458445.0
1   2019-05-01 18:04:55 Zawisza 2005-01-14 18:05:00 120.0   97.0    False   True    6458445.0   6458445.0
2   2019-05-01 18:05:00 Zawisza 2005-01-14 18:05:00 NaN     NaN     False   False   NaN         NaN
3   2029-01-01 17:58:45 800A    2029-01-14 17:59:10 NaN     NaN     False   False   NaN         NaN
4   2029-01-01 17:58:50 800A    2029-01-14 17:59:10 139.0   NaN     False   True    NaN         7192783.0
5   2029-01-01 17:58:55 800A    2029-01-14 17:59:10 138.0   NaN     False   True    NaN         7192783.0
...........................................................
...........................................................
....................................................
.....................................
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **apply**.

Create the function:

```
def foo(x):
    if not bool(x['epic_include']) and not bool(x['vs_include']):
        return None
    else:
        if not pd.isna(x['twist_mrn']):
            return x['twist_mrn']
        else:
            return df['twist_mrn'].iloc[df.iloc[x.name:]['twist_mrn'].first_valid_index()]
```

So, apply:

```
df['twist_mrn'] = df.apply(foo, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    datetime    patient_name    dischargeDate   HR  SpO2    epic_include    vs_include  twist_mrn
0   2014-01-05 18:04:50     Zawisza     2014-01-05 18:05:00     119.0   98.0    False   True    4654843.0
1   2014-01-05 18:04:55     Zawisza     2014-01-05 18:05:00     120.0   97.0    False   True    4654843.0
2   2014-01-05 18:05:00     Zawisza     2014-01-05 18:05:00     NaN     NaN     False   False   NaN
3   2014-01-29 17:58:45     800A    2014-01-29 17:59:10     NaN     NaN     False   False   NaN
4   2014-01-29 17:58:50     800A    2014-01-29 17:59:10     139.0   NaN     False   True    4719848.0
5   2014-01-29 17:58:55     800A    2014-01-29 17:59:10     138.0   NaN     False   True    4719848.0
6   2014-01-29 17:59:00     800A    2014-01-29 17:59:10     138.0   96.0    False   True    4719848.0
7   2014-01-29 17:59:05     800A    2014-01-29 17:59:10     138.0   96.0    False   True    4719848.0
8   2014-01-29 17:59:10     800A    2014-01-29 17:59:10     138.0   96.0    False   True    4719848.0
9   2014-01-29 17:59:15     Barber  2014-01-29 18:17:15     138.0   96.0    False   True    4719848.0
10  2014-01-29 17:59:20     Barber  2014-01-29 18:17:15     138.0   96.0    False   True    4719848.0
11  2014-01-29 17:59:25     Barber  2014-01-29 18:17:15     138.0   95.0    False   True    4719848.0
12  2015-03-04 21:19:45     800A    2015-03-05 01:00:15     NaN     NaN     False   False   NaN
13  2015-03-05 00:53:10     800A    2015-03-05 01:00:15     NaN     NaN     False   False   NaN
14  2015-03-05 00:55:40     800A    2015-03-05 01:00:15     NaN     95.0    False   True    4163407.0
15  2015-03-05 00:55:45     800A    2015-03-05 01:00:15     NaN     95.0    False   True    4163407.0
16  2015-03-05 00:55:50     800A    2015-03-05 01:00:15     NaN     94.0    False   True    4163407.0
17  2015-03-05 00:55:55     800A    2015-03-05 01:00:15     81.0    93.0    False   True    4163407.0
```

Comment: This line df['twist_mrn'].iloc[df.iloc[x.name:]['twist_mrn'].first_valid_index()] get the first rec_num not null from a specif line (x.name return the index).